# Trusting a certificate without adding it to Trust Manger

Tags: android, security, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am working on an Email app on Android. When we connect to Server which presents us a self-signed certificate, and we do not have it in our Trust manager then we show a verbose message to the user telling about the potential risk trusting this certificate like MITM.
But if user still consents to trust this certificate anyways, then we use an Insecure trust manager, that trusts any certificate for this connection.
This just increases the probability of MITM attacks.

To mitigate this (to some extent), we store the serial number and the issuer DN of the certificate locally. 
Now next time when user try to connect to this server we check for the equality of serial number + issuer DN of the certificate with the one we have locally.

Is this a right approach/solution to the given problem?
Or is there something else we can do?

**P.S.** One solution can be that the user get the certificates and add to the default trust manager by installing it. But this will be beyond the scope of my app.

Comment: Why can't you use a real certificate on the server?

Comment: So the thing is, its an Email app. If we connect to a server that chose to have a self signed certificate, I as a client cant do much about it. So I have  two choices here, either I do not connect to this Server at all because it presents a certificate that I cant trust. This, I feel, is sometime unfair to the end user who is not aware of this whole thing. So showing a warning message and asking for user consent sounds to be a fine thing for me. But at the same time I want to keep it as safe as possible. Hope I made myself clear.